# JQuery Navigation Bar preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my test code. The `preventDefault()` isn't working. The alert is coming, but the link is being followed. What is wrong with my code?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JQuery Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="Links1" id="link1" onclick="nav_bar($(this));">Nav Bar Link 0</a><br/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function nav_bar(thisObject){
        var $objectID = thisObject.attr("id");
        var $objectClass = thisObject.attr("class");
        alert("A Link with Class : " + $objectClass + ", And ID Of : " + $objectID + " Was. Clicked!");
        thisObject.preventDefault();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've passed a jQuery object, which has not `preventDefault` method. You've to pass the `Event` too, which has the said method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method preventDefauls belongs to event, not to object.
I fixed your code:

```js
function nav_bar(e, thisObject) {
 var $objectID = thisObject.attr("id");
 var $objectClass = thisObject.attr("class");
 alert("A Link with Class : " + $objectClass + ", And ID Of : " + $objectID + " Was. Clicked!");
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>JQuery Testing</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <a href="#" class="Links1" id="link1" onclick="nav_bar(event, $(this));">Nav Bar Link 0</a><br/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: That fixed it. Alexander Dayan. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

As you have attached the event using an `onclick` attribute, you need to `return false` to prevent the default behaviour:

```
<a href="#" class="Links1" id="link1" onclick="return nav_bar(this);">Nav Bar Link 0</a><br/>
```

```js
function nav_bar(thisObject) {
    var $el = $(this);
    var $objectID = $el.attr("id");
    var $objectClass = $el.attr("class");
    alert("A Link with Class : " + $objectClass + ", And ID Of : " + $objectID + " Was. Clicked!");
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively if you attach your events via jQuery you can use `preventDefault`, but note that it needs to be called on the *event* not the element that raised the event:

```
<a href="#" class="Links1" id="link1">Nav Bar Link 0</a><br/>
```

```js
$('#link1').click(function(e)
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(this);
    var $objectID = $el.attr("id");
    var $objectClass = $el.attr("class");
    alert("A Link with Class : " + $objectClass + ", And ID Of : " + $objectID + " Was. Clicked!");
}
```

Comment: I wish the system allowed to vote for multiple answers. your answer really taught me something new @Rory McCrossan.  Thanks you very much!